# Fit Swift string in database VARCHAR(255)

Tags: swift, string, utf-8, swift2

I'm trying to get a valid substring of at most 255 UTF8 code units from a Swift string (the idea is to be able to store it an a database `VARCHAR(255)` field).

The standard way of getting a substring is this :

```
let string: String = "Hello world!"
let startIndex = string.startIndex
let endIndex = string.startIndex.advancedBy(255, limit: string.endIndex)
let databaseSubstring1 = string[startIndex..<endIndex]
```

But obviously that would give me a string of 255 characters that may require more than 255 bytes in UTF8 representation.

For UTF8 I can write this :

```
let utf8StartIndex = string.utf8.startIndex
let utf8EndIndex = utf8StartIndex.advancedBy(255, limit: string.utf8.endIndex)
let databaseSubstringUTF8View = name.utf8[utf8StartIndex..<utf8EndIndex]
let databaseSubstring2 = String(databaseSubstringUTF8View)
```

But I run the risk of having half a character at the end, which means my UTF8View would not be a valid UTF8 sequence.
And as expected `databaseSubstring2` is an optional string because the initializer can fail (it is defined as `public init?(_ utf8: String.UTF8View)`).

So I need some way of stripping invalid UTF8 code points at the end, or – if possible – a builtin way of doing what I'm trying to do here.

**EDIT**

Turns out that databases understand characters, so I should not try to count UTF8 code units, but rather how many characters the database will count in my string (which will probably depend on the database).

According to @OOPer, MySQL counts characters as UTF-16 code units. I have come up with the following implementation :

```
private func databaseStringForString(string: String, maxLength: Int = 255) -> String
{
    // Start by clipping to 255 characters
    let startIndex = string.startIndex
    let endIndex = startIndex.advancedBy(maxLength, limit: string.endIndex)
    var string = string[startIndex..<endIndex]

    // Remove characters from the end one by one until we have less than
    // the maximum number of UTF-16 code units
    while (string.utf16.count > maxLength) {
        let startIndex = string.startIndex
        let endIndex = string.endIndex.advancedBy(-1, limit: startIndex)
        string = string[startIndex..<endIndex]
    }
    return string
}
```

The idea is to count UTF-16 code units, but remove characters from the end (that is what Swift think what a character is).

**EDIT 2**

Still according to @OOPer, Posgresql counts characters as unicode scalars, so this should probably work :

```
private func databaseStringForString(string: String, maxLength: Int = 255) -> String
{
    // Start by clipping to 255 characters
    let startIndex = string.startIndex
    let endIndex = startIndex.advancedBy(maxLength, limit: string.endIndex)
    var string = string[startIndex..<endIndex]

    // Remove characters from the end one by one until we have less than
    // the maximum number of Unicode Scalars
    while (string.unicodeScalars.count > maxLength) {
        let startIndex = string.startIndex
        let endIndex = string.endIndex.advancedBy(-1, limit: startIndex)
        string = string[startIndex..<endIndex]
    }
    return string
}
```

Comment: I'm confused... do you want the result to be 255 *characters*, or 255 *bytes*?

Comment: I want the result to be stored in a `VARCHAR(255)`, so at most 255 bytes. But I want a valid UTF8 sequence so It may have to be less.

Comment: What database are you using? `VARCHAR(255)` in MySQL means 255 *characters* in the column's encoding, which may be more than 255 bytes.

Comment: Yes I know. My database uses UTF8.

Comment: Then again I'm even more confused. If your database allows you to store 255 *characters* (potentially considerably more than 255 *bytes*), then why are you trying to limit the string to 255 *bytes*?

Comment: Ok I understand now. I should not try to do this since the database will store 255 characters regardless of the number of UTF8 bytes required to encode them. I was running some tests and having some issues with emojis, but I think the problem is different. I may have something to do with the fact that some emojis require more than one character. I'll look into it. Sorry for the dumb question, I'll just delete it.

Comment: In MySQL with Character Set 'utf8', one CHAR is equivalent to one UTF-16 code unit, using 3-bytes maximum. And in 'utf8mb4', one CHAR is equivalent to one unicodeScalar code unit, using 4-bytes maximum. And both are not equivalent to Swift's `Character`. Someone may have interest in this fact. Please do not delete.

Comment: So this will probably depend on the database and maybe on the database version... What do you think of my edit ? Also I'm using Postgres, not MySQL, do you happen to know how characters are counted ? Otherwise I'll try to find out.

Comment: It actually is DBMS-dependent, including versions. And in recent (I do not know about older versions) PostgreSQL, varchar(n) count length by "characters", and each character can contain one unicodeScalar code unit. Which is not equivalent to Swift `Character`.

Comment: Swift `String` has a `UnicodeScalar` view. Is it equivalent to that ?

Comment: Yes, counting by `UnicodeScalar` fits for PostgreSQL, as in your EDIT 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I write in my comment, you may need your `databaseStringForString(_:maxLength:)` to truncate your string to match the length limit of your DBMS. PostgreSQL with utf8, MySQL with utf8mb4.

And I would write the same functionality as your EDIT 2:

```
func databaseStringForString(string: String, maxUnicodeScalarLength: Int = 255) -> String {
    let start = string.startIndex
    for index in start..<string.endIndex {
        if string[start..<index.successor()].unicodeScalars.count > maxUnicodeScalarLength {
            return string[start..<index]
        }
    }
    return string
}
```

This may be less efficient, but a little bit shorter.

```
let s = "abc\u{1D122}\u{1F1EF}\u{1F1F5}" //->"abc"

let dbus = databaseStringForString(s, maxUnicodeScalarLength: 5) //->"abc"(=="abc\u{1D122}")
```

So, someone who works with MySQL with utf8(=utf8mb3) needs something like this:

```
func databaseStringForString(string: String, maxUTF16Length: Int = 255) -> String {
    let start = string.startIndex
    for index in start..<string.endIndex {
        if string[start..<index.successor()].utf16.count > maxUTF16Length {
            return string[start..<index]
        }
    }
    return string
}

let dbu16 = databaseStringForString(s, maxUTF16Length: 4) //->"abc"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This seems to be working rather well. Let's just hope that Swift and Postgresql have the same definition of unicode scalar. Swift seems to be using this one : http://www.unicode.org/glossary/#unicode_scalar_value